# comparing if a date falls between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date-range

Please see this if possible in SQL Server:

I have two tables with the following attributes:

Table **A**

```
AId prm_code   dateTrom      dateTo
1  sql/mn/01   01/01/2017   30/03/2017
2  sql/mn/01   01/04/2017   30/06/2017
```

Table **B**

```
BId  prm_code    qty   price   tDate   
1    sql/mn/01   10    10      03/01/2017
2    sql/mn/01   1     11      03/01/2017
3    sql/mn/01   12    100     05/01/2017
4    sql/mn/01   5     50      10/02/2017
5    sql/mn/01   20    10      15/03/2017
```

Now I would like to create a query to get the **AId** from Table **A** and all other rows from Table **B** like following when the tDate from Table **B** falls between dateFrom and dateTo in Table **A**

```
    BId  prm_code    qty   price   tDate     AId
1    sql/mn/01   10    10      03/01/2017    1
2    sql/mn/01   1     11      03/01/2017    1
3    sql/mn/01   12    100     05/01/2017    1
4    sql/mn/01   5     50      10/02/2017    1
5    sql/mn/01   20    10      15/03/2017    1
```

Thanks

Comment: [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Why are you skipping March 31? What have you tried so far? Please post your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use **JOIN** with **BETWEEN**

```
SELECT B.BId, B.price, B.qty, B.prm_code, B.tDate, A.AId   
FROM [dbo].[TableA] AS A  
JOIN [dbo].[TableB] AS B    
    ON B.tDate BETWEEN A.dateFrom AND A.dateTo
```

Comment: Beaut, never seen it before, ON...BETWEEN, I added an extra row to Table B just to see and it produced AID 2 which is good.